# How to store data into an Access database with java

Tags: java, database

I have this project where I have to store student grades into a database using Microsoft Access, using java.

I have no idea how to start, I've tried looking for tutorials but nothing helps. Help, I'm new with Java Language.

This is what i have so far, but the program just runs, nothing happens

```
package javadatabase;

import java.sql.*;

public class JavaDatabase {


    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        try
        {

            Class.forName("Net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://JavaDatabase.accdb");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            String rol = "ADSADADS";
            String name = "Laere";
            String contact = "019209010";
            String marks = "65";

            String query = "Insert INTO Table2(Roll , Name, contact, Marks) "
                    + "     Values('"+rol+"' , '"+name+"' , '"+contact+"' , '"+marks+"')";

            st = con.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(query);

            System.out.println("Successful");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR:  " + ex.getMessage());
        }    
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you entered the correct path for JavaDatabase.accdb ?

Comment: like the file location? or the name of the database?

Comment: I mean file location

Comment: yes the file is located in documents

Comment: When I run the program, it just runs without any errors but nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: Now I get this error                                                                                          
 run:
ERROR:  No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\Users\andin\Documents\JavaDatabase.accdb
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)